# Facebook and Revmob

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, revmob

I'm integrating revmob and facebook sdk 4.3.6 in my project. When thing is working perfect but when user close fullscreen ad and not already logged in facebook. Facebook activity throws exception and game crashed.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.itchyfingerz.laststand/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

But if user close fullscreen ad and already logged in with facebook everything works perfectly.

Please help me and if needs any more information do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry you're having problems.  We have created an internal task and will look into this.

Comment: looking forward to hear from you soon...Thanks..

Comment: Damn, I've the same issue with latest revmob sdk and facebook sdk 4.3.6 (latest)... If I close the ads, my game just crash with the same error code as yours... Any way to fix this ?

Comment: @LucaD'Amico  Are you still having problems with this? our new SDKs don't require modifying the main activity so this may be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We have new v5.0.2 beta version of the SDK which should play nice with other plugins.

Check Brian's answer in this thread [How to work with Facebook SDK for Unity and Vuforia for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928723/how-to-work-with-facebook-sdk-for-unity-and-vuforia-for-android)